# How do I automate do a phone number lookup online for a large list of names & addresses I have in CSV?

Tags: phone-number

I have a large list of names & addresses (currently in an excel file). I need to perform a phone number lookup
I can't seem to find any APIs for phone number lookup, and the only solution I can find is a regular phone book lookup where you type in name and address one by one into the browser and find the number eg canada411.ca
How can I automate this process and get the numbers I need in bulk?

Thanks

Comment: Your best bet is probably to contact canada411.ca (or someone else) and ask them if they provide an API, or if they can run this search for you and mail you back the spreadsheet with details filled in. I expect they'll want to charge you either way. You could try setting up some tools e.g. Selenium to automate look ups on their website but you ought to check the Ts&Cs first to make sure this isn't disallowed, and be prepared to hit daily usage limits for searches too.